# C#: Store number in database with 2 places of decimal. Eliminate unwanted numbers

Tags: c#, oracle, floating-point

I have a field NumberValue1 declared like this

```
public double NumberValue1 { get; set; }
```

NumberValue1 has a datatype of Number in the
oracle database

I read in a value from an excel file which is
22.55

```
[[col8Value is an object type]]
```

I then did this.

```
NumberValue1 = col8Value == null ? 0 : Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(col8Value),2)
```

When I inserted this into the database I got the number below stored

22.550000000000001

Why is it bringing the other ...00001.

I just want it to show the 22.55 which is the initial number I loaded

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using decimal instead of double?

Comment: Well Double != Number in Oracle particularly, but how is this not just a normal floating point precision issue? If you want Oracle to always store just 2 decimal places, then instead of using Number generically in Oracle, use Number(Precision, Scale)

Comment: Try using the Decimal data type instead of Double for both your application code and database column type.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). If you want decimal places use a decimal type instead of a floating point type.

Comment: it's the problem of representation of 10-base numbers in binary format, which is used for storing a double in memory.

Comment: I only have control over my application. I am unable to change the database column type

Comment: Then format it to two decimal places. Another simple alternative is to store it as an integer (eg: store 22.55 as 2255, 22 as 2200, etc.)

Comment: @user2320476 You don't need to change db column type, just use different datatype in app (hint - use decimal)

Comment: I just used decimal and it works like magic. Thanks so much. I changed all double to decimal.

Comment: @user2320476 - please write up your last comment as an answer, then accept it (you may need to wait a while).  SO is a Q&A site, and as such thrives on Questions with Answers.  Comments are for transient info and metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
private int NumberStoreHundreths
public double NumberValue1 
{ 
     get
          {
             return ((double)NumberStoreHundreths)/100;
          } 
     set
          {
             NumberStoreHundreths = (int)(value*100);
          }
}
```

kind of old school, but should work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change db column type, just use different datatype in app (hint - use decimal). (Answer by Koka Chernov)

This fixed my problem in 2015.